# Ubuntu 18.04 SFTP Group: one user has permissions, the other doesn't

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, sftp, ubuntu-18.04, user-groups

Following [this guide](https://devanswers.co/configure-sftp-web-server-document-root/) I have created a group `sftp_users` that I use for SFTP access only.

I created two users, `user1`, `user2`

I then added both to to group

```
sudo usermod -a -G sftp_users user1
sudo usermod -a -G sftp_users user2
```

Here is the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
Match Group sftp_users
    ChrootDirectory /projects/websites/
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    X11Forwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    PasswordAuthentication yes
```

This allows them to login via SFTP but not shell.

Finally, for each websites I have I run the following:

```
sudo chown -R root:sftp_users /path/to/root_of_website*
```

Now, the problem is that when I SFTP into the server as `user1` I can do whatever, create edit or delete files and folders. When I SFTP with `user2`, I cannot do anything with the error `open for write: permission denied`.

Both users are part of the `sftp_users` group and both users have the same configurations. What could the problem be ?

Here is a screen showing the permissions

[image]

Thank you.

**EDIT**
Here is the output for the command `namei -l /path/to/root_of_website*`, where `root_of_website` is the root of one of the websites.

[image]

Comment: Please show `namei -l /path/to/root_of_website*`.

Comment: @grawity Hi, I edited my post and I included a screen of the output. Thank you